# How set Mongo cursorTimeoutMillis to NoTimeout?

Tags: mongodb

I use Mongo and I want to disable cursor timeout. According to [this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8188) I can set timeout by **cursorTimeoutMillis** parameter and it works. But I can't completely remove timeout. I already tried **-1** and **0** but it doesn't work.

Tell me please, what should I pass to remove cursor timeout?

Comment: What client library are you using? What programming language do you use? Or are you talking about server configuration? It is okay to edit your question to include the answer to those questions.

Comment: I am speaking about mongo server settings

Answer (score 1):

The cursor timout is checked [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/d9a3c65f642ce90b1cf6f725786654998676cd20#diff-9ce186d60525c07bc6de44251475b504R177). You can see [only a few lines above](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/d9a3c65f642ce90b1cf6f725786654998676cd20#diff-9ce186d60525c07bc6de44251475b504L171) that you can disable the timeout by passing the [noTimeout](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.addOption/#DBQuery.Option.noTimeout) option on the cursor query. You do that from the client side when opening the cursor:

```
var cursor = t.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout);
```

I don't think it is possible to do this from the server configuration. But you can set the `cursorTimeoutMillis` options to the maximum `int` on your machine. On 64-bit systems this is `9223372036854775807` which corresponds to about 200 million years. On 32-bit systems it is only `2147483647` which is a measly 24 days, but most applications can probably live with that timeout as well.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about noTimeout flag. Unfortunately, it can't be use for aggregation and map reduce (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6036) and set global cursor timeout is workaround for this issue